# Hidden scrollbar reappears after state change?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, menu, scrollbar, sliding

I'm having an issue with hidden scrollbars after a div is hidden then shown again. Everything works fine on page load, but after the divs are closed with the toggle button and re-opened, the scrollbar is still invisible but the screen real estate where the scrollbar would be is rendered, pushing the nav menus away from the screen edge and creating a blank space. Could someone kindly point me in the right direction here? I can't provide any sample code, but you can see a live demo on [my website](http://logd.uphero.com/) using the "Slider" skin. The left and right navigation menus are what is giving me problems. Thanks in advance. :)